# os.rename Not Working On AWS Workspace, FileNotFoundError

Tags: python, amazon-web-services

This is strange and I'm not sure if it's due to me environment or not (appears so).

On may computer I try to run the following and it works fine

```
import os
os.rename('C:\\Users\\travissimpson\\Downloads\\filename-test.zip','C:\\Users\\travissimpson\\Downloads\\filename-test2.zip')
```

On my AWS Workspace (AWS VM) I run the following and I get a file not found error.

```
import os
os.rename('D:\\Users\\travissimpson\\Downloads\\filename-test.zip','D:\\Users\\travissimpson\\Downloads\\filename-test2.zip')
```

Result:

```
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: 
'D:\\Users\\travissimpson\\Downloads\\filename-test.zip' -> 
'D:\\Users\\travissimpson\\Downloads\\filename-test2.zip'
```

The OS of the AWS Workspace is Windows Server 2016 Datacenter. The OS of my computer where it works is Windows Server 2012 R2

Comment: can't you check manually on server what folders do you have ? And check if you really have this file and disk `D:`

Comment: I created the files myself for testing, they are indeed on the machine in that exact location name exactly the same, which is what's so perplexing. It doesn't seem to actually have to do with the location, which is why the error is odd. At first I thought it may be that Python is installed on the C: and my file is on D: but I'm giving the full path.

Comment: you can use Python script with `os.listdir()` to list files in D:\\, later in D:\\Users, etc. to check what you have in folders. You can also display names with some char before and after - ie. "|" in `print(f"|{name}|")` - to see if there is no spaces in name (at the beginning and at the end) which you may not see normally.

Comment: Once you're run your code once, it won't work again because the file has been renamed. Make your code also do 'os.listdir()` with the path part of the filename `os.path.split(filepath)[0]` I think - does it list the target file?

Comment: Occam's razor is gleaming at you in the sunlight: the simplest possible explanation for the error message "file not found" is that the file is not in fact there.

Comment: @barny I'm sure according to Python that technically might be true in the end but without knowing why it's strange. Also I have also tried changing my directory with os.chdir. https://ibb.co/510gbLj

Comment: Sigh. I thought I was showing file extensions, turns out I wasn't, so my file was actually named filename-test.zip.zip instead of filename-test.zip.

Comment: So Occam *was* correct. If you'd done the `os.listdir()` thing you'd have seen what Python sees the filenames in the folders, and that would have told you straight away what was wrong.

Comment: That is correct, that's what I did after responding to you and saw exactly that.

Comment: @furas If you'd like to put your comment as an answer I'd be happy to mark it as the solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Python script with `os.listdir()` to list files in `D:\\`, later in `D:\\Users`, etc. to check what you have in folders.

You can also display names with some char before and after - ie. `"|"` in `print(f"|{name}|")` - to see if there is no spaces in name (at the beginning and at the end) which you may not see normally.

```
import os

for item in os.listdir('D:\\'):
    print(f"|{item}|")
    #print("|{}|".format(item))  # older pythons

for item in os.listdir('D:\\Users'):
    print(f"|{item}|")
    #print("|{}|".format(item))  # older pythons

# etc.
```

This way you can see what names see Python.

Answer (score 0):

There is no magic. If you get "File not found" then the file is not there, point.

To confirm, on your remote Windows box try:

```
dir D:\Users\travissimpson\Downloads\filename-test.zip
```

–– I am sure this will tell you something like "File not found".

Disclaimer: I didn't use Windows since the XXth century :)